# How to use a variable's contents to declare another variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem that I hope to use one variable's contents as another variables name in javascript. In this case, I do not know what is the contents in that variable, I only know it is a text type and I hope the variable I need to declare will use that text as its name.

Anyone could kindly give me some suggestion of how to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Like dynamic variables? check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413414/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-dynamic-variables-with-javascript#2413453

Answer (score 3):

You can't really, [variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variables) names (*identifiers*) are static (as long as you don't use `eval`) in a scope.

However, you can easily [use objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) for that. Accessing properties of them with a variable name is easy, use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators):

```
var obj = { someprop:"someval", otherprop:… },
    name = "someprop";
obj[name]; // "someval"
```

If you need a global variable, you can do that by accessing it as a property of the global object (in browsers: `window`):

```
variable = "someval";
var name = "variable";
window[name]; // "someval"
```

Answer (score 3):

You are able to use a variable's value as another variable's name as long as the latter variable can be accessed via bracket notation, e.g.

```
var firstVariable = 'secondVariable';

window[firstVariable] = 'secondValue';
// you now have a global variable 
// named "secondVariable" with the value "secondValue"
```

Note I would not recommend cluttering the global namespace like this; it was just for demonstration.