# Can variable in javascript generate variables?

Tags: javascript

Let's think about this:

```
var list = [a1:"123",b2:"234",c3:"345"];
```

This `list` obj can create variables by key name like this?

```
var a1 = list[0];   
var b2 = list[1];  
var c3 = list[2];
```

Comment: Indent a line with 4 spaces to get code to render as code blocks -- quotes (`>`) are meant for text from elsewhere or a quote from someone else.

Comment: and [Is there an easy way to create dynamic variables with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2413414/218196)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `[]` notation, you can only create arrays with numeric indexes. To have named properties, you must use `{}` object notation:

```
var list = { a1: "123", b2: "234", c3: "345" };
```

You can then access them as `list.a1`, `list.b2`, and `list.c3`.

Comment: I mean create those variables automatically.

Comment: @RyanYiada: what do you mean by "automatically"? You mean a for loop or something like that?

Comment: @RyanYiada You might be able to do it with `eval`. But why? There's probably something wrong with your design if you need to do this. You can access object properties by name with `list[name]`.

Comment: @Barmar thank you.I just want to know this way is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear. What you show in the example is valid. But you could also create variable names like you suggest like

```
for( var key in list ) {
  window[key] = list[key];
}
```

This way you will end up having `a1`, `b2` and `c3` variables with the desired value, however, these will be globals.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a mistake, you are trying to merge hash array and regular array. You should either announce an array like this:

```
var list = ['123', '234', '345']
```

and then

```
var a1 = list[0]
```

and so on, or announce it like hash array and it will look like this

```
var list = {'a':'123','b':'234','c':'345'}
var a1 = list.a
```

Comment: Is this last line valid?

Comment: Sry, was thinking 'bout an array.