# Changing the JavaScript with a Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

I want to add a variable and add something to a functions content.

```
var variable1;

function myFunction() {
    alert(variable1);
    return variable1;
}
```

I want to change that to:

```
var variable1;
var variable2;
function myFunction() {
    alert(variable1);
    alert(variable2);
    return variable1;
}
```

I want that the changes are applied to a my main html file so that the next time the page is called the changes are in effect.

I already have a Servlet that can produce a new html page but I don't know how to change the JavaScript part of an already existing page.

Edit: so basically I need something like:

```
 request.getFunction(myFunction).addBeforeReturn(alert(variable2));
```

Comment: Is the javascript embedded in the html your are producing?

Comment: This might help [http://stackoverflow.com/a/2413453/2850474](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2413453/2850474)

Comment: If you already have the servlet producing HTML content what prevents you from adding few more lines to that code?

Comment: thx for the answers I edited my question abit to make my point clear.

@yellen : yes but I could change that if that is a major problem (quite new to javascript and html)

Comment: @amarnath thx that tells me how to add a variable, so now I need a way to edit functions

Comment: @RaviH yes but that is not what I want. I want to edit the main html file's javascript part. Pls read again the sentence before that where I state that I have a Servlet that...

Comment: @Selphiron I give up!