# JS - Iterate through an array of objects and use values to create vars

Tags: javascript, loops, object

If I build an array of objects.

```
var destinations = [{
  id:   '277',
  title:'Alicante',
  lat:  '38.35782',
  lng:  '-0.5425632',
  content:  '<p>string</p>'
},{
  id:   '275',
  title:'Amsterdam',
  lat:  '52.3745292',
  lng:  '4.7585347',
  content:  '<p>string</p>'
},{
  id:   '250',
  title:'Belfast',
  lat:  '36.1673368',
  lng:  '27.6853392',
  content:  '<p>string</p>'
}, {
  id:   '263',
  title:'Bergerac',
  lat:  '44.8519854',
  lng:  '0.4532777',
  content:  '<p>string</p>'
}]
```

How do I use a loop and use the data to create variable names and properties? What is the function that would iterate through the array and create variables (which I am using to populate a Google Map). I am reading through so many code examples but I can't seem to get it right.

I would expect the following function to create four variables (marker277, marker275, marker250, marker263), with position taken from objects in the array in a similar fashion, but it doesn't work.

```
for (var i = 0, l = destinations.length; i < l; i++) {
  var obj = destinations[i];
  var marker[obj.id] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: obj.lat, lng: obj.lng}
  });
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The only problem i can see with your code that it does not return anything. You declared marker inside for loop. But should be outside and initialized as an array. Better to use  hashmap as your ids are not regular.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413414/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-dynamic-variables-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not create variable names but tries to set marker to the array marker. You most likely want to have map of markers

```
var markers = {};
for (var i = 0, l = destinations.length; i < l; i++) {
  var obj = destinations[i];
  markers[obj.id] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: obj.lat, lng: obj.lng}
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the marker lat long expect float values, so you should try using parseFloat(). Also you should store the marker in an array to keep it, like this.

```
var markers = [];
for (var i = 0, l = destinations.length; i < l; i++) {
  var obj = destinations[i];
  var lat = parseFloat(obj.lat);
  var long = parseFloat(obj.lng);
  markers[obj.id] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: lat, lng: long}
  });
}
```